# python - pandas installation fail because of microsoft visual c++

Tags: python, pandas, anaconda

I am using anaconda to run my python code and installed python 3.4. On top of this I am trying to install `pandas` library using `pip install pandas`. But it is showing me error

```
python34.lib(python34.dll) : fatal error LNK1112: module machine type 'x64' conflicts with target machine type 'X86'
error: command 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\\VC\\BIN\\link.exe' failed with exit status 1112
```

I have installed micrsoft visual c++ 2010 Express ENU. Can someone please help me to install this?

Comment: Did you try installing it via conda instead of pip?

Comment: Yes, I tried that also. But it didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

A work around I like to use for this type of thing is to use the precompiled version.

https://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/